# vue 3 + vuetify 3: Unknown node type in node creation at Array.map (<anonymous>)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I'm migrating from **vue2** to **vue3** and also to **vuetify 3**. However, I can't set up vuetify 3 properly. I get the below error

> Syntax Error: Error: Unknown node type in node creation at Array.map (anonymous)

In the following lines:

```
in ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VList/VListItem.css
in ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VCard/VCard.css
in ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VBtn/VBtn.css
```

I tried to fix it by following links

[[Bug Report][3.0.0-alpha.0] Vuetify 3 'Unknown node type in node creation' bug #14179](https://githubhot.com/repo/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/14179)

[vuetify-loader](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vuetify-loader)

But no success.

`vuetify.js`:

```
// Styles
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";
import "vuetify/styles";
import colors from "vuetify/lib/util/colors";

// Vuetify
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";

    export default createVuetify({
      theme: {
        themes: {
          options: { customProperties: true },
          light: {
            primary: "#FF6D00",
          },
          dark: {
            primary: "#FFCA28",
          },
        },
      },
      icons: {
        iconfont: "mdi", 
      },
    });
```

`main.js`:

```
const app = createApp({
  data: function () {
    return {
      currentRoute: window.location.pathname,
    };
  },    
  computed: {
    ViewComponent() {
      return routes[this.currentRoute] || NotFound;
    },
  },
  render() {
    return h(this.ViewComponent);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an older version of autoprefixer that doesn't support `@supports` fully (https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/1391). Updating postcss and autoprefixer to the latest versions will fix the error.

Comment: How are you meant to fix this, just

```
npm install postcss
npm install autoprefixer
```

I'm not sure what the 'fix' is saying to do.  I had neither of these installed previously (migrating from vue 2 to vue 3) and installing them hasn't fixed this :-(

Comment: They're likely a dependency of some other package like vue-cli, you can use https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-explain to figure out what other versions are installed and why.